# Android USB Not Recognized Sometimes

Tags: android, usb, driver

Programming on my Android device in Intellij was working fine for a while, then all of a sudden my Android device started not being recognized-- "USB Not Recognized". I have tried re-installing my drivers, restarting my phone, restarting my computer, and setting up a new project but nothing seems to work. My phone is still recognized about half the time, but I randomly get the USB Not Recognized error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just solved my issue with a really weird fix. It turns out that with a lot of wear, the tongue (which is the little prong that is in the middle of where the USB cord goes on the phone) that the connector goes around can get bent. I figured this out because pushing the front end of my connector down on the tongue made the connection work and pushing the connector up made the connection stop. I read somewhere that if you take a knife or a toothpick and push the tongue up gently, the tongue will bend slightly and return to a position where it can form a proper connection, and oddly enough I tried it and it worked. Weird. Hopefully this helps someone. Just don't push too hard up on the tongue and only do this if you're sure you don't have a driver issue.

Answer (score 7):

Same. I get this error very often.
This is how I usually fix it:

Use another cable.

Turn Android debugging off and on again.

Reboot the phone.

Use another USB-port.

Use another USB-port with another cable.

Dunno why. Any pro's who can answer this? :)

Comment: Tested with two cables, three USB-ports, tried switching Android debugging, now I only have one hope: the turn-off, turn-on again!

Comment: Now it connects, but gets disconnected instantaneously with these errors: `[21279.984022] usb 2-2: new full-speed USB device number 65 using uhci_hcd
[21280.164026] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[21280.444022] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71`

Answer (score 1):

This works on ubuntu: sudo adb start-server

Comment: You'd figure this would be covered by restarting the computer

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Storage. Click settings dots ‘USB Computer connection’.

Check the ‘Media Device’ (MTP) check box. If already checked, try checking/unchecking it.

This worked for me

Comment: there  is no "USB Computer connection" option there. how to go to this option in new androids?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with the USB and it is working now perfectly.
Use your usb pin to push it up by connecting it to the mobile.
connect the cable with your mobile then slightly move it towards UP.
But be carefull while doing that as it may bent it completely.